# Checks how many arguments a function takes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

With `arguments.length` I can see how many arguments were passed into a function.

But is there a way to determine how many arguments a function can take so I know how many I should pass in?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`Function.length` will do the job (really weird, in my opinion)

```
function test( a, b, c ){}

alert( test.length ); // 3
```

By the way, this length property is quite useful, take a look at [these slides](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#87) of John Resig's tutorial on Javascript

EDIT

This method will only work if you have no default value set for the arguments.

```
function foo(a, b, c){};
console.log(foo.length); // 3


function bar(a = '', b = 0, c = false){};
console.log(bar.length); // 0
```

The `.length` property will give you the count of arguments that require to be set, not the count of arguments a function has.

Comment: You can even parse the result of `Function.toString()` to inspect the names for the arguments. Ugly, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Note that this won't work for native functions (at least in chrome).

Comment: Appearantly it does, because `Number.prototype.toFixed.length` returns `1` which means 1 argument ;)

Answer (score 13):

## Edge cases

**Beware**, before counting on `fn.length`, there are some edge cases where the result may not be what you expect:

```js
const fn1 = ( a, b ) => {}; //       length: 2
const fn2 = ( a = 0, b ) => {}; //   length: 0
const fn3 = ( ...params ) => {};//   length: 0
const fn4 = ( a, b = 1, c ) => {};// length: 1
```

`fn.length` doesn't seem to recognize default values or rest operator.

You can mess with this [codePen](https://codepen.io/seb-rom-o/pen/zQbeWo?editors=0010)

Comment: Why exactly one would want to define a function with optional argument placed before required argument? I refer to `fn2` and `fn4`. I've never seen this in practice, functions with optional arguments before the required ones, have you?

Comment: Yess you are true, that is just for the sake of example. Like the title suggest it is about edge cases. The goal is to demonstrate the exact behavior of fn.length (in this case that it ignores everything after the optional argument). But you are true **to remind that this is a bad practice** :)

Answer (score 9):

The `arity` property specifies the number of arguments the current function expected to receive. This is different to `arguments.length` which indicates how many actual arguments were passed in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arity

### Edit

Note that `arity` has been deprecated since v1.4.  The correct way to get the number of arguments expected is now `function.length` as suggested by Harmen.

Comment: arity is deprecated. from your link: "arity is no longer used and has been replaced by the length property."

Comment: @MartinodF - Ah, so it has.  Thanks for pointing that out, it's been quite a while since I needed to reflect on a function in javascript.  It appears Function.length is the appropriate way after 1.4.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that either, until I read the page you linked ;) Also, it appears that at least Chrome 9 (which I'm running) doesn't even have `.arity` anymore.

Comment: <sarcasm> because `fn.length` makes so much sense </sarcasm> (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻