# Passing parameters to a javascript function

Tags: java, rhino

So here's the deal: I read [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/)
and started *trying* to use Rhino. So far I got how to invoke a function, and how to get its return. What I can't do is pass the function's parameter. Here's my code:

```
ScriptEngineManager engineMgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineMgr.getEngineByName("ECMAScript");

String js = "";
js += "function add(a, b) {";
js += " var sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);";
js += " println(sum);";
js += "}";

engine.put("a", 3);
engine.put("b", 5);

Object returnn = null;
try {
    engine.eval(js);

    Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable) engine;
    returnn = invocableEngine.invokeFunction("add");
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    System.out.println("Script error.");
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    System.out.println("Method error.");
}

System.out.println(returnn);
```

I get no Exception whatsoever, but the return comes back as NaN. I tried printing a and b (The parameters) and they always come as null. If this is not the best way to invoke a function, please just point me to some useful thread. (Which I did not find on my own)

TYVM in advance

Comment: You can get rid of the `.put` calls. And instead call `invokeFunction("add", 3, 5)`

Comment: It worked. Than you! But if I can ask something else.. I won't always know how many parameters the method has. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: See the answer below (by @Dan Howard)

Comment: In JavaScript you mean? Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138012/checks-how-many-arguments-a-function-takes-in-javascript

Comment: Btw, if you want to get a return value you'll need to have a `return sum;` statement in your JavaScript function definition. The return value will appear as return value of `invokeFunction` and needs to be cast `(double)` or sth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Object params[] = {1,2,3};
Invocable invocable = (Invocable) script.getEngine();
invocable.invokeFunction("myFunction", params);
```

Comment: `invocable.invocableEngine` should probably be `invocableEngine.invokeFunction`