# Check the number of parameters a function as a parameter takes

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using features of either TypeScript or vanilla JavaScript, how can I tell how many parameters a user-specified function takes and have the program react accordingly? For example, say a package includes a function `foo` that takes a function named `bar` as a parameter. Is it possible to check that `bar` is meant to take, say, two and only two parameters and throw an error if it takes more or fewer than two? One of the practices I follow is to always cover every edge case in a function/package, and so I want to make sure the program is able to handle itself properly with unexpected inputs for functions as parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4138012/3001761. Not in TS, because it _doesn't exist at runtime_.

Comment: *"Is it possible to check that bar is meant to take, say, two and only two parameters and throw an error if it takes more or fewer than two?"* Note that you can't really do that, because `foo` may use a rest argument (`function foo(...args)`) or may even declare no parameters (`function foo()`) and then use the `arguments` pseudo-array to access the arguments it was passed. In both cases, `foo.length` is `0`, but in both cases it may actually use the arguments you give it.

Comment: Not really reliably. As the dupe says `fn.length` will give the arguments, however that can be misleading parameters like `(a, b = 4)` will make the length `1` when the function *can* receive two. And parameters like `(a, ...b)` ill also make the length `1` but the function can accept as many arguments as you give it.

Comment: @VLAZ - Oooh, yeah, default parameter values blow up `length` as well. Good one. (I don't really understand the rationale for that.)