# Can I somehow know in Lua how many arguments a function has beforehand?

Tags: function, lua

I didn't think so, but since accordingly to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4138036/2805176) other languages seem to have a way... Do you think it'd be possible to know how many arguments a function requires even before it is really run/called?

My intention is have the chance to run or not a certain function in base of its arguments count in order to make sure (or more sure at least) my scripts are not going to run the wrong function while parsing all of the possible function container tables in _G, in order to avoid possible error messages just in case another user has a *namesake* one (which can be more or less probable depending on the function's name).

P.S. Or, of course, another way to can differentiate one function from another before running it in base of its arguments (or not) that you could think?

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.7

Comment: First off, thank you! But is this the only way? I normally don't care to make use of debug library when necessary, but given that I'd have to check all possible namesake functions in _G, I wondered if the known lack of efficiency of debug library could be a problem in the long term. Although surely the impact would be so little that I'm probably worrying for no reason...

Comment: For getting the number of arguments of a function, there is no loop, no lack of efficiency.

Comment: Then perfect and thank you again! I'll have to brush up my little debug library knowledge in order to can apply that and also, while I'm at it, see if there could be other check I could do with it that could help on differentiate this kind of functions to ensure even more any possible unwanted call. E.g. since my scripts are supposed to be located in a separated specific folder, maybe using "source" to check and compare their location on disk could also help, but I may have to think a little more about it...